# .NET/C# decimal serialization problems

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have a class with a decimal property & I'm serializing & deserializing using JSON.NET. The problem I'm having is that if say the decimal value is 100000000000023063.0 , when I deserialize it gets converted to 100000000000023000. I have checked the JSON & it's definitely recorded as 100000000000023063.0.

I've looked into it &

```
decimal.Parse("100000000000023063.0")
```

=

```
100000000000023063.0
```

but

```
var d = (decimal)100000000000023063.0
```

=

```
100000000000023000
```

I can get around this problem by storing as a string & have a property that does decimal.Parse() but does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because `100000000000023063.0` is a `double` constant, which you're then converting to `decimal`, and precision is getting lost.

Write it like this instead:

```
var d = 100000000000023063.0M;
```

The `M` suffix tells the C# compiler that the number is a `decimal` constant.

In fact you don't even need the decimal separator for this - i.e. `1M == 1.0M` and both are `decimal`s.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I'm getting the value "100000000000023063.0" in XML via a web service. I then parse it & to create my class & serialize the class using JSON.NET & store it in a database for future reference. It looks like JSON.NET 4.0 fixes the issue with decimal precision.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are casting a double to a Decimal whereas you should be defining the value as a Decimal: i.e.

```
var q = 100000000000023063.0M;
```

The M suffix indicates that the numeric constant is of type Decimal